# Add double quotes to text file

Tags: unix, sed, double, quotes

I have a text file delimited by semi-colon with multiple rows with a header possibly. I have to add double quotes to each of the columns in the text file. I have tried to get the individual pieces work using sed. however when combined they don't run.

My commands:

1. `sed "s/;/\";"\/g  a.txt` - (replace columns with ";" (ex:d;"b";"c";"f)
2. `sed "s/^/\"/"g  a.txt`  - (– replace double quotes around first column)
3. `sed "s/$/\"/"g a.txt`  - (replace double quotes around last column)

When I combine them as below:

```
sed "s/;/\";"\/g";s/^/\"/g";s/$/\"/ g"  a.txt
```

This doesn't run. I can combine only 2 of above sed statements and run but not all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose scripts (and variables) in single quotes unless you absolutely NEED double quotes for a specific purpose, e.g. to let the shell expand variables. So your scripts should be (with some other things cleaned up):

```
sed 's/;/";"/g' a.txt - (replace columns with ";" (ex:d;"b";"c";"f)

sed 's/^/"/' a.txt - (– replace double quotes around first column)

sed 's/$/"/' a.txt - (replace double quotes around last column)
```

and combined:

```
sed 's/;/";"/g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/' a.txt
```

which can be reduced a bit in some seds (those that support EREs) to:

```
sed 's/;/";"/g; s/^\|$/"/g' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that.

```
sed '2,$s/\([^;]*\)/\"\1"/g'
```

Starting from line 2 to preserve header.